# amcharts5 - fine-tuning multi-column legend for mobile

Tags: legend, amcharts5

Trying to figure out how amcharts calculates the column width in a multi-column legend using the responsive feature. Goal here is to center a legend across the bottom of a chart when the responsive settings specify 2 or more columns.

One of 2 problems keeps happening:
a) using x: am5.p50 and centerX: am5.percent(50), and centerX doesn't seem to accurately center the entire legend - I have to punt by tweaking centerX to shift the legend to the right.

b) if I get too aggressive in trying to center the legend, it resolves to a single column, which looks a bit iffy.

I think amacharts is calculatingg the width of each column (in the legend) by assuming some max length for the categories (in that column).

So my real question is - is there a way to specify the max width of each column (in a legend)?

[image]

```
      responsive.addRule({
          relevant: am5themes_Responsive.widthL,
          applying: function () {
              // chart.set("layout", root.verticalLayout);

              // apply position
              legend.setAll({
                  y: null,
                  centerY: null,
                  x: am5.p50,
                  centerX: am5.percent(40), //tweaked to shift legend to the right

                  dx: 0,
                  dy: 0,

                  layout: am5.GridLayout.new(root, {
                      maxColumns: 2,
                      maxRows: 3,
                      fixedWidthGrid: false
                  }),
              });

              // apply font size
              legend.labels.template.setAll({
                  fontSize: ".8rem",
                  fontWeight: "300"
              });

          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
                // adjust labels
                legend.labels.template.setAll({
                    fontSize: ".8rem",
                    fontWeight: "300",

                    maxWidth: 20,
                    // oversizedBehavior: "truncate", 
                    // ellipsis: "...",
                });
```

Oddly enough:
maxWidth by itself limits the label len, but more than 20px!

- furthermore, maxWidth  (by itself) seems to fix the multi-column issue noted in my original question.

oversizedBehavior does what it says it does, but either:

- the text is truncated to an unreadable len (i.e. 20px) OR
- if maxWidth is set to a higher value, then the multi-column issue rears its ugly head - i.e. what should be 2 columns resolves to a long single column

bottom line - just using maxWidth for the legen.labels makes it possible to use a multi-column grid in the legend, and it can be properly centered w/o triggering a single column...